# How to close a web browser window in c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, browser

I am trying to make an application which opens and closes a browser window after a period of time being open. For example, to open a youtube video and then close the browser window 1 minute later automatically after it finishes.

I am opening the window in my default browser by using:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("example-site.com");

Any help on the closure of this window would be great. (P.s. I know how to make the program wait for a period of time so don't need help with that part)

Comment: look up using javascript so if they click on a close button for example you can show a message asking them if they want to close.. then execute that javascript `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "YourCloseScript", "window.close()", true);` or if it's windows you can do a simple google search on this.. there are plenty of examples or use `Process.Start()` method

Answer (score 0):

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start return value is a **Process**. You can assign this process to a variable (lets call it myprocess) and later use the variable to close the process with the Close method, **myprocess.Close()**.

Comment: To expand on that, you may want to look at the .WaitForExit() method of the process once it's created since you are waiting for the user to close the browser/watch the video.